# C# mp3 in background

Tags: c#, audio, background, mp3

I want to play a mp3 in background of my program ( without opening the media player for example --> System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Franz\Music\Americana.mp3") ( I don't want to use...)

Now i tried it like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class sound
{
   [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
   private static extern int mciSendString(string @cmd, StringBuilder ret, int retLen, IntPtr hwnd);
   [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
   private static extern int mciGetErrorString(int errCode, StringBuilder errText, int errLen);
}

private void txbStart_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   mciSendString("play \""+C:\Users\Franz\Music\Americana.mp3+"\", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
}
```

But it doesn'T work? but why? I'm a beginner in c# ...

Comment: How on earth would you play an MP3 without something in place that can play it?

Comment: i mean that you don't see the media player and when you close the program the sound should stop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different methods you could use, some of which are explained below:

- http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/292695/playing-mp3-in-c
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3dbfb9a3-4e14-41d1-afbb-1790420706fe/how-to-play-mp3-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3352/A-low-level-audio-player-in-C
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562692%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
    player.SoundLocation = "My Wav File.wav";
    player.Play();

now it works :)